# Unable to understand a line of Less_termcap

Tags: less

This problem is related to the [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/35169/unable-to-change-bolding-font-to-highlighted-font-in-less).

The line in my .zshrc

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'     # begin blinking
```

The following seems to mean

- \$ starts the expression
- ' -- ' says everything in the brackets matters
- \E apparently says that apply the following command
- [01 seems to refer to the beginning of a file
- ; seems to indicate between the beginning of the previous to
- 31m which seems to be the end of a file

The statement is still confusing. Some pattern must match "a begin" and "blinking".

**How do you read the line?**

Comment: I need to solve this problem first to solve the other problem here: http://serverfault.com/questions/35169/unable-to-change-the-font-in-bold-to-yellow-font-in-less

Comment: See also [Documentation on LESS_TERMCAP_* variables?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/documentation-on-less-termcap-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an ANSI color sequence.

- The $'...' means interpret backslash-escaped characters (like \e or \n) (see the "Quoting" section of the bash man page)
- \E is the escape character (ASCII 27 decimal)
- [ is just a square bracket
- so Esc-[ begins the color sequence
- 01 is "bright"
- ; delimits colors
- 31 is "red"
- m is the end of the color sequence

The sequence Esc-[ 0 m resets to default colors.

Try

```
 echo $'\E[01;31m'Hello$'\E[0m' Masi
```

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) Wikipedia article for more information.