# How can you browse the links in Man?

Tags: unix, manual

This question is based on [the thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/35169/unable-to-change-the-font-in-bold-to-yellow-font-in-less/35268#35268).

I would like to read the documentation of the link "Expression" which is in the mentioned-thraed.

The problem is that I cannot use cursor to locate the link and then press `enter`.

**How can you read a link in your Find's manual?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of "`man find`" try "`pinfo -m find`" or "`pinfo find`".  "`info find`" will also work, but is harder to use.

Comment: Are Info's manuals completely substitutes for Man's manuals?

Comment: "pinfo -m" gives you man's manuals.  Without the -m option, you'll get a different (info) version of the docs unless there is none (in which case it will return the man page), which may be more or less complete.  Many GNU packages update the info pages and don't touch the man pages, other packages update man and have an outdated info page.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't really links. They're just underlined text.

Comment: You are correct. --- Is it possible to browse links in Man similarly as in Info?

Comment: with "pinfo -m" you can the "links".   Man doesn't really have links, though.